# Running C code with mktime inside PHP's exec

Tags: php, c, date, mktime

I am having a strange problem with PHP and a C script that uses the current time. My program is a little complex, but the problem narrows itself to this:

I have this C code which prints the date 1 minute ago, the current date, and the date 1 minute from now:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
  char date[9];
  time_t rawtime;
  struct tm * ptm;
  int i;

  time(&rawtime);
  ptm = gmtime(&rawtime);
  ptm->tm_min--;

  for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    rawtime = mktime(ptm);
    ptm = gmtime(&rawtime);
    snprintf(date, 9, "%d %d %d", ptm->tm_mday, ptm->tm_hour, ptm->tm_min);
    printf("%s\n", date);

    ptm->tm_min++;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

When I run this in the shell, I get correct results (the print format is day of the month, hour, minute):

```
$ ./test
17 20 7
17 20 8
17 20 9
```

However, when I execute it through PHP I get strange results. This is the PHP code:

```
<?php
exec("path_to_exec/test", $output);
echo "$output[0]<br/>";
echo "$output[1]<br/>";
echo "$output[2]<br/>";
?>
```

And this is the output:

```
17 20 7
17 17 8
17 14 9
```

The hours are clearly wrong. Anyone has any idea of what could be causing this?

Comment: What do you get when you `var_dump($output)`?

Comment: @jprofitt `array(3) { [0]=> string(8) "17 17 40" [1]=> string(8) "17 14 41" [2]=> string(8) "17 11 42" }`

Comment: Any particular reason why you want to use C to fetch date information? What's wrong with PHP's built-in date functions?

Comment: @NullUserExceptionఠ_ఠ My C program is bigger and uses the time/date to calculate what I want. I was just trying to show the result in the page, but it was coming out wrong because the hours are wrong inside the C code (although they appear to be right when I use the shell).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with the C code, not the PHP code:

When you do this:

```
rawtime = mktime(ptm);
```

The `ptm` pointer is modified by the `mktime` function. Therefore, if you do this:

```
rawtime = mktime(ptm);
ptm = gmtime(&rawtime);
```

You're actually **manipulating the pointer twice**, hence the weird results.

Instead of the above, just do:

```
mktime(ptm);
snprintf(...);
```

You'll get the expected result. So, the complete `for` loop code would be:

```
mktime(ptm);
snprintf(date, 9, "%d %d %d", ptm->tm_mday, ptm->tm_hour, ptm->tm_min);
printf("%s\n", date);
ptm->tm_min++;
```

Comment: Thank you. That solved it. I didn't know that `mktime` modified the pointer. But why does it work in the shell and not in PHP?

Comment: @nmat: Honestly? No idea. It shouldn't have worked at all in the first place. There's probably something missing from your example that I'd need to answer that.

Comment: Not really. I actually copied and pasted this in a different file before posting here to make sure of what was happening. I saw [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/mktime/) that the return value of mktime was "the specified time since the Epoch encoded as a value of type time_t" (if I hadn't skipped to the "Return Value" section, I would have also read that it modifies the pointer). Anyway, what I wrote is indeed redundant, but shouldn't be giving wrong results I think...

Comment: I'd have to check the assembler to figure it out I guess.

Comment: Don't bother. Thanks for the answer.